# Error Handling When Searching The Shodan API

Tags: python, python-2.7, shodan

I'm trying to write a Python script that will search the Shodan API and return ID, CVE and Description.  As some of my search results ('java' for example) do not have an established CVE (or CVE key), my script chokes.  I'm aware that I need to wrap the search in try/except error handling, but I've not had any luck with what I've been able to find researching the web.  Here is the error I get and below that is the code.  Thanks very much in advance.

--------Error-------

```
    print '%s: %s: %s' % (exploit['id'], exploit['cve'], exploit['description'])
KeyError: 'cve
```

--------My Code------

```
from shodan import WebAPI
api = WebAPI("my shodan key")

user_selection = raw_input("Enter something: ")
print "searching for", (user_selection),"....."

results = api.exploitdb.search(user_selection)

for exploit in results['matches']:
    print '%s: %s: %s' % (exploit['id'], exploit['cve'], exploit['description'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use `dict.get` and provide it a default value to be returned where the key doesn't exist:

```
print '%s: %s: %s' % (exploit.get('id', '[blank]'), exploit.get('cve', '[blank]'), exploit.get('description', '[blank]'))
```